# NextAuth authorizes user but user info is null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement NextAuth with Credentials (email and password). 
I have set up my mongodb for this. I also set up `/api/proile/` route to post login credentials and tested it out with Postman, returns user correctly.

But the problem starts with after logging in. when I log in, credentials return in the vscode terminal (I console log in `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` with `console.log(credentials)` but in the browser it authorizes the user, i can access and view protected routes and stuff, but when I log the session in front-end, it displays as `null` for user information as you can see in the picture below; 
[image: consolelog1]

here is my `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` code;

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../../util/mongodb';

const options = {
  providers: [
 
    Providers.Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log(credentials);
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/profile/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
        const user = await res.json();

        // const user = { id: '1', name: 'Suat Bayrak', email: 'test@test.com2' };

        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
  },


  database:             `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@nextjs-academia-    sb.ki5vd.mongodb.net/test`,
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

by the way, when I use static user credentials like i commented in the code above, it works perfectly fine and returns session info correctly... 
 
Also here is my `/pages/signin.js`

```
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function SignIn() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('submitted!');
    signIn('credentials', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      //   email: 'test@test.com',
      //   password: '1234',
      callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/about',
      redirect: false,
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.error !== null) {
        if (result.status === 401) {
      setLoginError(
        'Your username/password combination was incorrect. Please try again'
      );
    } else {
      setLoginError(result.error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(result);
    router.push(result.url);
  }
});
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Email
        <input
          name='email'
          type='text'
      value={email}
      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
    />
  </label>
  <label>
    Password
    <input
      name='password'
      type='password'
      value={password}
      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
    />
  </label>
  <button type='submit'>Sign in</button>
</form>
  );
}
```

also here is my github repo for this whole code;
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/sbayrak/nextauth-authentication)

UPDATE: At first login, user info displays on the terminal but after I refresh the page, it says `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';

const options = {
  providers: [
     
    Providers.Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log(credentials);
        let user;

        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/profile/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
        const arrayToJson = await res.json();
        user = arrayToJson[0];

        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user) {
      return user.userId && user.isActive === '1';
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt(token, user) {
      if (user) token.user = user;
      return token;
    },
  },

  database: `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@nextjs-academia-sb.ki5vd.mongodb.net/test`,
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

so the problem was at `callbacks` section of the code. Now its working fine